# Write the result of SQL Query to file by Apache Flink

Tags: java, hive, apache-flink, flink-sql

I have the following task:

1. Create a job with SQL request to Hive table;
2. Run this job on remote Flink cluster;
3. Collect the result of this job in file (HDFS is preferable).

**Note**

Because it is necessary to run this job on remote Flink cluster i can not use **TableEnvironment** in a simple way. This problem is mentioned in this ticket: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/FLINK-18095. For current solution I use adivce from http://apache-flink-user-mailing-list-archive.2336050.n4.nabble.com/Table-Environment-for-Remote-Execution-td35691.html.

**Code**

```
EnvironmentSettings batchSettings = EnvironmentSettings.newInstance().useBlinkPlanner().inBatchMode().build();
// create remote env
StreamExecutionEnvironment streamExecutionEnvironment = StreamExecutionEnvironment.createRemoteEnvironment("localhost", 8081, "/path/to/my/jar");
// create StreamTableEnvironment
TableConfig tableConfig = new TableConfig();
ClassLoader classLoader = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader();
CatalogManager catalogManager = CatalogManager.newBuilder()
                                              .classLoader(classLoader)
                                              .config(tableConfig.getConfiguration())
                                              .defaultCatalog(
                                                  batchSettings.getBuiltInCatalogName(),
                                                  new GenericInMemoryCatalog(
                                                      batchSettings.getBuiltInCatalogName(),
                                                      batchSettings.getBuiltInDatabaseName()))
                                              .executionConfig(
                                                  streamExecutionEnvironment.getConfig())
                                              .build();
ModuleManager moduleManager = new ModuleManager();
BatchExecutor batchExecutor = new BatchExecutor(streamExecutionEnvironment);
FunctionCatalog functionCatalog = new FunctionCatalog(tableConfig, catalogManager, moduleManager);
StreamTableEnvironmentImpl tableEnv = new StreamTableEnvironmentImpl(
    catalogManager,
    moduleManager,
    functionCatalog,
    tableConfig,
    streamExecutionEnvironment,
    new BatchPlanner(batchExecutor, tableConfig, functionCatalog, catalogManager),
    batchExecutor,
    false);
// configure HiveCatalog
String name = "myhive";
String defaultDatabase = "default";
String hiveConfDir = "/path/to/hive/conf"; // a local path
HiveCatalog hive = new HiveCatalog(name, defaultDatabase, hiveConfDir);
tableEnv.registerCatalog("myhive", hive);
tableEnv.useCatalog("myhive");
// request to Hive
Table table = tableEnv.sqlQuery("select * from myhive.`default`.test");
```

**Question**

On this step I can call **table.execute()** method and after it get **CloseableIterator** by **collect()** method. But in my case I can get a large count of rows as a result of my request and it will be perfect to collect it into file (ORC in HDFS).

How can I reach my goal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Table.execute().collect()` returns the result of the view to your client side for interactive purpose. In your case, you can use the filesystem connector and use `INSERT INTO` for writing the view to the file. For example:

```java
// create a filesystem table
tableEnvironment.executeSql("CREATE TABLE MyUserTable (\n" +
    "  column_name1 INT,\n" +
    "  column_name2 STRING,\n" +
    "  ..." +
    " \n" +
    ") WITH (\n" +
    "  'connector' = 'filesystem',\n" +
    "  'path' = 'hdfs://path/to/your/file',\n" +
    "  'format' = 'orc' \n" +
    ")");

// submit the job
tableEnvironment.executeSql("insert into MyUserTable select * from myhive.`default`.test");
```

See more about the filesystem connector: https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-1.11/dev/table/connectors/filesystem.html

Comment: Thank you so much, I will try to use this opportunity. But I have one more question:
For my case it will be better to create table by HiveCatalog, but I have problems with it (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63719627/how-to-create-table-in-hive-with-orc-format-by-hivecatalog-from-apache-flink). Can you also help me with this question please?